# Framework7 Toggle with confirmation before change

Tags: html-framework-7

I want to create a toggle with Framework7, where the user should confirm before the toggle is turned off (and only when turned off, not when turned on - maybe this is relevant). My toggle is created like this:

```js
var toggle = app.toggle.create({
  el: '#myToggle',
  on: {
    change: function() {
      if (toggle.checked) {
        // let user confirm to uncheck toggle before
      } else {
        // check toggle and do something
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not possible to add a confirm to toggles, I just created two segmented buttons that kinda look like a toggle:

```html
<div class="list no-hairlines">
  <ul>
    <li class="item-content">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title">My Toggle</div>
        <div class="segmented segmented-strong toggle-buttons">
          <button id="btn-toggle-off" class="button button-small">off</button>
          <button id="btn-toggle-on" class="button button-small button-active">on</button>
          <span class="segmented-highlight"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then inside the click event I just call a confirm:

```js
$$('#btn-toggle-off').on('click', function(evt) {
  app.dialog.confirm(text, title, callbackOk, callbackCancel);
}
```

And inside *callbackOk*, I switch the button-active class:

```js
$$('#btn-toggle-off').addClass('button-active');
$$('#btn-toggle-on').removeClass('button-active');
```